# How to return the simplified direction list from a given direction list by eliminating pairs of consecutive complimentary directions?

Tags: python, list, while-loop, break, terminate

I want to return the simplest direction set from a list of given directions. So, if the direction set has `"SOUTH"` followed by `"NORTH"`, or vice versa, they should cancel out each other; same with `"WEST"` followed by `"EAST"`, or vice versa.

So, for instance, if the given direction list is `["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"]`, the correct output should be to return the simplified list `['WEST']`. My logic is to do it in the following way:

- The list has 7 elements. In the first pass, the elements 0 & 1 get removed (`"NORTH", "SOUTH"`), and 3 & 4 also get removed (`"EAST", "WEST"`). So the list is now `['SOUTH', 'NORTH', 'WEST']`. Compare the length of the list before and after the removal; if they are the same, break - else, repeat. Since the old and new lengths are 7 and 3 respectively, it repeats the process.
- The list now has 3 elements. In the second pass, elements 0 & 1 get cancelled (`'SOUTH', 'NORTH'`). So the list now becomes `['WEST']`. Again, Compare the length of the list before and after the removal; if they are the same, break - else, repeat. Since the old and new lengths are 3 and 1 respectively, it repeats the process.
- In the third pass, no element pair gets removed. Compare the length of the list before and after the removal; if they are the same, break - else, repeat. Since the old and new lengths are 1 and 1 respectively, it breaks the process and returns the list as `['WEST']`.

My code to implement this is as follows:

```
arr = ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"]

while True:
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        try:
            len_old = len(arr)
            if ( ((arr[i]=='NORTH' and arr[i+1]=='SOUTH') or (arr[i]=='SOUTH' and arr[i+1]=='NORTH')) or
                 ((arr[i]=='EAST' and arr[i+1]=='WEST') or (arr[i]=='WEST' and arr[i+1]=='EAST')) ):
                arr.remove(arr[i])
                arr.remove(arr[i])
            len_new = len(arr)

            if len_new==len_old:
                break

        except:
            pass

arr
```

But the problem is, it never terminates. When I manually force the code to stop and check the value of of the list and the old and new lengths of the list, it returns the correct values:

```
print(arr)
print(len_new)
print(len_old)
>>>
['WEST']
1
1
```

So, what's wrong with the code? Why does it not break despite reaching the break condition, and how do I fix it?

Comment: `break` in Python can only break the innermost loop. It is `for`, in your case. `while` never gets broken. Either set a flag that will break `while`, or wrap everything in a function and use `return` as a multilevel break.

Comment: You have 2 loops: `while` and `for`. `break` only breaks out of the `for` loop.

Comment: Also, note that your algorithm is unable to handle `["WEST", "SOUTH", "EAST", "NORTH"]`.

Comment: So how do I fix it? I put the if-break condition again at the end of the for loop; it breaks after the first pass returning `['SOUTH', 'NORTH', 'WEST']`, which is incorrect.

Comment: @Amadan That's the requirement - lists like `["WEST", "SOUTH", "EAST", "NORTH"]` and `["NORTH", "WEST", "SOUTH", "EAST"]` are already in the reduced form for the problem I'm solving, because in my problem, only pairs of directions should cancel each other, not quadruple directions. But yeah, in general you're right - these sort of quadruple, or even octuple, etc directions should also cancel each other - but that's for another day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program will never terminate. Outer look does not have any termination condition. Interloop termination may not execute for all input. I have rewritten the code, it is working for provided test cases

```
def dirReduc(arr):

        if len(arr)<=1:

            return arr

        len_old = len(arr)
        arr = checkDirection(arr)
        len_new = len(arr)

        if len_new==len_old:
            return arr
        else:
            arr= dirReduc(arr)

        return arr


def checkDirection(arr):
        if len(arr)<=1:
            return arr
        for i in range(len(arr)-1):
            try:
                if ( ((arr[i]=='NORTH' and arr[i+1]=='SOUTH') or (arr[i]=='SOUTH' and arr[i+1]=='NORTH')) or
                     ((arr[i]=='EAST' and arr[i+1]=='WEST') or (arr[i]=='WEST' and arr[i+1]=='EAST')) ):
                    arr.remove(arr[i])
                    arr.remove(arr[i])
                    return arr
            except:
                print('Catching Except')
                return arr



    main_arr = ["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"]
    main_arr = dirReduc(main_arr)
    print('Final Result')
    print(main_arr)
```